# Cost of Web Server that hosted and delivered text only

Tags: database

We are developing an application that needs a web server to interact with the two (or more) entities involved. They will not ever see anything on the web, but the server is required for the transfer of data between them. It's sort of a holding point. Now, the only thing the server is going to be holding is textual data. The two entities are going to be doing the work with the data.

I was wondering what the cost of this type of server would be. Since it would be JUST a database with no front end, would it make sense to employ a service through Amazon or Google that just holds data for me to access instead of buying a server and making my own database?

The amount of data can grow very large however it's only text, and all data over a day old will be deleted for the most part every day.

Thanks!

Comment: Any particular database platform? MySQL? SQL Server? etc?

Comment: Doesn't matter to me.

Comment: I saw that you had a great answer by Piers - did that answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to decide what platform you're going to be running. Microsoft-based platforms will cost more than open source ones.

Amazon/RackspaceCloud would be the best route to go down.

I run a single rackspace cloud server with Apache and MySQL which costs me about $20 a month.

One thing it's worth noting is that if the server isn't going to be interacting with the outside world, just your servers, it's definitely worthwhile using AWS or Rackspace as then you can use their internal network which is (usually) free.

Comment: How much data are you using (dealing with) monthly?

Comment: According to the control panel .025 in and 0.28 out. As I said before, if you use the internal IP rather than the external IP any bandwidth used is free.